# Daisy chain multiple PCB with an existing IDC cable

Tags: serial-bus, expander

I'm not sure, if I just miss the obvious, but I'm stuck on seemingly simple problem and can't find a solution.

I have a series of PCBs, I want to daisy chain. The number is between 8 and 12(max).
The distance between each about 500mm (just in case that matters).

I have an existing IDC cable with 4 free wires.
Each PCB has 8 devices, which I would like to switch on and off, from a microcontroller located on the first PCB.
So I need 8 digital outputs on each PCB.

If possible I would like to find a solution with the following criteria:

- I would **NOT** like to have an address, that needs to be set on each PCB. So something like an I2C IO-Expander such as the [PCA9557](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/NXP-Semicon-PCA9557PW-118_C141380.pdf) is somewhat ruled out (or is there a smart way to set the address?).
- I would **NOT** like to add an extra cable or one with more pins
- As I will replace the existing PCB's, I am free to design whatever circuit onto the PCB's.

So with what bus or circuit can I do this / How I can daisy chain these PCB, with the given criteria?
[image]

Comment: You must ask a question.

Comment: Question is: How I can daisy chain these PCB, with the given criteria? - I edited and added it.

Comment: The problem is underdefined - you need to explain what these four wires should be used to actually do to the devices on the PCBs. Nobody but you can define the interface requirements.

Comment: @Andyaka I changed the description of the PCBs to be more clear. I need 8 digital output on each PCB, so a total of 64 to 96 outputs from these 4 wires. The crucial point is the IDC cable. Otherwise I could just use something like a 74x595 shift register and daisy chain the serial out to the next PCB serial in.

Comment: Why do you say this: *So I need 8 digital outputs on each PCB*??

Comment: @Andyaka I improved the picture and hope it is more clear now, what I mean.

Comment: If you select "2", does every PCB sets output "2"? Or can each PCB have a different output? (ie, are you using 4 bits to select 1 of 8, or to select 1 of 96?) If it is 1 of 96,  guess you could use multiple voltage levels.

Comment: It's 1 out of 96 - I would like to be able to set each output on each PCB individually

Comment: So each cable has 4 free wires what are the other ones doing?

Comment: @Parker the cable has several power rails and the 4 wires were previously used for something else but are now free.

Comment: From the PCA datasheet and ignoring your up to 12 for the sake of the argument, is the "3 address pins allowing up to 8 devices on the I2C-bus/SMBus" not what you want by using dip-dwitches on each board to set the adress?

Comment: @winny yes, that would be an option - but I would like to avoid it. Because the final application needs a huge number of these devices and I would like to avoid that somebody needs to set thousands of DIP switches. That's why I for now rules it out as an option.

Comment: I see. How do you want to differentiate between them on your bus?

Comment: @winny There is always only 8 to 12 devices on 1 bus / IDC cable.

Comment: That didn’t answer my question. Do you need them to get their ID automatically from their physical position? Some other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably position dependant addressing, i.e. the position of the board is it's address. However it can't be done with a straight flat cable, you need to either interrupt the chain at each board or do some mechanical shifting on the ribbon like in the old floppy drive flats.

If the boards have some kind of intelligence you could devise a dynamic address assignation but you'll need some way to identify the boards (like a jumper or something to put the board in setup mode).

Answer (score 1):

You can create position-dependent addressing by having each board receive the signal and regenerate it to the next board. This, pretty obviously, would need a small MCU on each board and at least one wire in the cable be connected point-to-point between boards instead of being connected straight through which you have stated you do not with to do.

You could do something like the following: the master sends a preamble on each packet consisting a bit for each target board followed by the data to the target board. The addressing bits would be zeros followed by a number of ones corresponding to the board number.

When a board receives the first "one", it would send on a "zero" but send on all remaining "one" bits in the preamble. When a board receives exactly a single "one" for the address, it knows it is the target and processes the data bits.

For example, assuming the controlling unit wants to address the 3th board of 8, it would send address "00000111" followed by the data to the first board.

- The first board receives "00000111" followed by the data. It passes on "00000011" followed by the data and ignores the packet.
- The second board receives "00000011" followed by the data. It passes on "00000001" followed by the data and ignores the packet.
- The third board receives "00000001" followed by the data. It passes on "00000000" followed by the data and processes the packet.
- Remaining boards receive "00000000" followed by the data. They pass on the same and ignore the packet.

This coding is nice in that there is no added latency as each board passes on the data with less than one bit time delay.

Another possible scheme would provide enumeration somewhat similar to USB: You would somehow put each board into setup mode where it listens to the input without passing it on. The controller uses a special address to assign the board its address and then the board switch to normal mode. (In normal mode, it passes everything on to the downstream board but listens for its assigned address.) The controller repeats this for each board until all have assigned addresses.

Once that enumeration process is completed, the controller can address each target board directly.

Note that I have ignored complications such as bit timing (clock line?), start/end packet signaling and maybe error detection. There are left for the reader.

This sort of thing ends up requiring more complicated cabling and more programming for the MCUs. This is the trade off vs. using jumpers on the boards or such.